# How can I navigate to next list item on a new page?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-listview

I have a list that I fetch from a provider file and display using ListView builder. The LIST page displays only the title of the item on the list and clicking on this title opens a new DETAIL with other related data.

I have created a button on the detail page that is supposed to navigate to the next item on the list to show its details too, but I have had a challenge implementing this.

I need help with this, please. Thanks in advance.

Here is the listview widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '/providers/lessons/lessons_provider.dart';
import '../lessons/lesson_item.dart';

class LessonGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const LessonGrid({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final subjectId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    final lessonData = Provider.of<LessonsProvider>(context);
    final lessons = lessonData.lessons;
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      itemCount: lessons.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: lessons[i],
        child: LessonItem(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the LessonItem widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '/providers/lessons/lesson.dart';
import '/providers/subjects/subject.dart';
import '/screens/lesson_detail_screen.dart';

class LessonItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const LessonItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final subjectData = Provider.of<Subject>(context);
    final lesson = Provider.of<Lesson>(context);
    return GridTile(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
            LessonDetailScreen.routeName,
            arguments: lesson.id,
          );
        },
        child: Card(
          color: lesson.isCompleted! ? Color.fromARGB(255, 186, 247, 217) : null,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text(lesson.title!, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the LessonDetailScreen

```
import 'package:classhall_app/providers/lessons/lesson.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

import '../providers/lessons/lessons_provider.dart';

class LessonDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/lesson-detail';

  @override
  State<LessonDetailScreen> createState() => _LessonDetailScreenState();
}

class _LessonDetailScreenState extends State<LessonDetailScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;
  late ChewieController _chewieController;


  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4');

    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio: 1,
      autoInitialize: true,
      allowFullScreen: true,
      placeholder: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
      // The Full Screen has an issue. Will implement it once it's resolved
      // fullScreenByDefault: true,
      looping: false,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final lessonId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    var loadedLesson =
        Provider.of<LessonsProvider>(context).findById(lessonId);
    final lessons = Provider.of<LessonsProvider>(context);
    var lesson = Provider.of<Lesson>(context);
    bool _showMore = true;

    void goToNextLesson() {
      int currentIndex = lessons.lessons.indexOf(lesson);
      var nextLesson = lessons.lessons[currentIndex + 1];
      lesson = nextLesson;
  }

    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('${loadedLesson.title}'),
            expandedHeight: 220,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              background: SafeArea(
                child: Chewie(
                  controller: ChewieController(
                    videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0, bottom: 8.0),
                    child: const Text(
                      'Lesson Summary',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 157, 197, 245),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '${loadedLesson.summary}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.black54,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10,
                    ),
                    child: ExpansionTile(
                        tilePadding: EdgeInsets.all(-10),
                        title: Text(
                          'Full Lesson',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            '${loadedLesson.content}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(136, 17, 17, 17)),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            softWrap: true,
                          ),
                        ]),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      TextButton.icon(
                        label: Text('Attempt Quiz', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                        style: ButtonStyle(),
                        onPressed: null,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.quiz, size: 50, color: Colors.red,),
                      ),
                      TextButton.icon(
                        label: Text('Next Lesson', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                        style: ButtonStyle(),
                        onPressed: goToNextLesson,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, size: 50, color: Colors.green,),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 800,
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use the following function to move to the next list item, but it is not working

```
void goToNextLesson() {
      int currentIndex = lessons.lessons.indexOf(lesson);
      var nextLesson = lessons.lessons[currentIndex + 1];
      lesson = nextLesson;
  }
```